# Create MySQL View in hook_schema()

Tags: database

I want to create a MySQL View in `hook_schema()` for a module I am developing.

Does anyone know how to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I already know how to resolve this issue.

In the .install file instead of trying to create a View in the hook_schema in hook_install you can just use de db_query and create the view. Don't forget in the hook_uninstall to drop the created View.

With my researches i found that is impossible to create a view directly in hook_schema like you do in a table, but if someone knows how to that please share.

Hope this help someone out there.

EDIT: Thanks for the correction kiamlaluno